# How select the excel sheet using for loop in R

Tags: r, rexcel

I want the app that I am developing automatically go to the excel sheet and calculate the transition probability matrix.

```
 action<-actions
    state<-states
    p<-array(0,c(length(state),length(state),length(action)))
    colnames(p)=state
    rownames(p)=state
    # transition probability matrix based on the action that we have choosen
    empiricala1<-read.xlsx("www/dynamic model.xlsx",1)
    empiricala2<-read.xlsx("www/dynamic model.xlsx",2)


    #show(empirical) calculate transition probability from historical data
    em1<-as.data.frame(empiricala1)
    em2<-as.data.frame(empiricala2)
    tab1 <- table(em1)
    tab2 <- table(em2)

    tab1<-addmargins(prop.table(table(em1$current,em1$nextstate),1),2)
    tab2<-addmargins(prop.table(table(em2$current,em2$nextstate),1),2)
    transitionprob1<-p[,,1]<-prop.table(table(em1$current,em1$nextstate),1)
    transitionprob2<-p[,,2]<-prop.table(table(em2$current,em2$nextstate),2)
    print(transitionprob1)
    print(transitionprob2)


    for(i in 1:length(action)){

      p[,,i]<-prop.table(table(em[i]$current,em[i]$nextstate),i)

    }
```

The error that I got is as following:

```
Error in em[i] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

How can I fix this problem.

Comment: Where is `em` declared? As to your error, see `?em`

Comment: The interpreter thinks that `em` is a function.

Comment: I want to address em1 and em2 whre you can see in the  'em1<-as.data.frame(empiricala1)
    em2<-as.data.frame(empiricala2)'

Comment: can you please tell me how to fix this problem

Comment: `lis <- list(em1,em2); for (i in 1:length(lis)) p[,,i]<-prop.table(table(lis[[i]][,"current"],lis[[i]][,"nextstate"]),i)`

Comment: Thanks it works, can you please explain why did you make a list from em1 and em2.

Comment: Because you were using a `for`-loop, so you want to iterate over something. You tried `em[i]`, but that just means that you have a vector `em` and want to iterate over its elements (`em[1]`, `em[2]`), NOT that you want `em1`, `em2`, etc. That's why the error occurred. To solve this, I just put `em1` and `em2` in a list, so that you can iterate over the list instead.

Comment: Thanks for your constructive explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so to expand on the comments...

You have two data frames `em1` and `em2`. You seem to want to apply the same operations to both data frames (e.g. `table(em1)` and `table(em2)`. This becomes really tedious to write, especially once you get way more variables.

What you tried to do, was:

```
for (i in 1:2) em[i]
```

The problem with this is that you do NOT get `em1` and `em2`. Instead, you get `em[1]` and `em[2]` and are thus referring to the `em` object (which does not exist to begin with).

There are a couple of ways to solve this.

**1. Move the data frames to a list**

```
lis <- list(em1, em2)
```

This way, you can iterate over the list with, for example, the `*apply` family or a `for`-loop:

```
sapply(lis, nrow)
for (i in 1:length(lis)) nrow(lis[[i]])
```

**2. Use `get`**

Another option is to use `get`, which allows you to provide a string and it will subsequently return the variable described in that string.

```
vec <- c("em1","em2")
sapply(vec, function(x) nrow(get(x)))
```

Note that using `get` is generally discouraged. I'd also opt for the first option instead.